# How to write every Nth file to new folder

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, directory

I have this code which scans folders and moves all files in each folder to a new one.

How do I make it so only every Nth file is moved?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save this file in the directory containing the folders (bb in this case)
# Then to run it, type:
# ./rencp.sh

# The first output frame number
let "frame=1"

# this is where files will go. A new directory will be created if it doesn't exist
outFolder="collected"

# print info every so many files.
feedbackFreq=250

# prefix for new files
namePrefix="ben_timelapse"

#new extension (uppercase is so ugly)
ext="jpg"

# this will make sure we only get files from camera directories
srcPattern="ND850"

mkdir -p $outFolder
for f in *${srcPattern}/*
do
mv $f `printf "$outFolder/$namePrefix.%05d.$ext" $frame`
if ! ((frame % $feedbackFreq)); then
    echo "moved and renamed $frame files to $outFolder"
fi
let "frame++"
done
```

Pretty sure I need to edit the line `for f in *${srcPattern}/*` but not sure of the correct syntax

Comment: In bash, parameter expansion is done before filename expansion, so your pattern, which you can write in a more compact form as `*$srcPattern/*` expands to all non-hidden entries in all directories with names einding in *ND850*. Note that this won't work properly if you have not at least one entry matching this pattern.

Comment: Should the numbering stay the same, that is increment in steps of 5 (1, 6, 11, 16, ...) or should it be consecutive (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)? Also, quote your variables.

Comment: Output numbering should be consecutive

Comment: Its like I need an if statement: if f modulus 5 = 0 .... mv $f .....

Comment: The line that prints out occasional info is doing a modulus on the frame number. You need a similar thing for the actual copy. `gap=8;if ! ((frame % $gap)); then; cp $frame $outfolder;fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files in the `ND850` folders are sequential when listed (i.e. padded frame numbers), and the folders themselves are in order, then the following code should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Maintain a counter, and the output frame number
let "frame=1"
let "outframe=1"

outFolder="collected"

# frequency
gap=5

namePrefix="ben_timelapse"

#new extension (uppercase is so ugly)
ext="jpg"

srcPattern="ND850"

echo "Copying and renaming 1 in every $gap files"

mkdir -p "$outFolder"
for f in *${srcPattern}/*
do
if ! ((frame % $gap)); then
    outfile=`printf "$outFolder/$namePrefix.%05d.$ext" $outframe`
    cp $f "$outfile"
    echo "copied $f to $outfile"
    let "outframe++"
fi
let "frame++"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your `mv` command after `do`:

```
if ! ((frame % 5)); then
  a=$((frame / 5));
  mv $f `printf "$outFolder/$namePrefix.%05d.$ext" $a`
fi
```

It will move `frame`=5,10, and so on, to `$outFolder/$namePrefix.00001.$ext`,`$outFolder/$namePrefix.00002.$ext`, and so on